# Redis and Services in Docker Containers

Tags: redis

I have a server running Ubuntu with Redis and Docker installed.  I am creating services to be hosted in Docker containers.  How do I connect a service running in a Docker container with Redis running outside of Docker?

I can ping the server. The ioredis driver cannot connect to redis. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED :6379

Answer (score 0):

Find your IP of host machine (local network IP).

Linux/Mac:

```
$ ifconfig
```

Windows:

```
$ ipconfig
```

For example it will be something like 192.168.1.43

Start your container with service and check if you can ping 192.168.1.43 from your container.

You can even start redis container to use redis-cli in order to test connection.

```
$ docker container run --rm -it redis sh
```

Inside container execute:

```
# redis-cli -h 192.168.1.43 PING
```

To make this work I had to disable firewall on my host machine. I am using fedora so the command is:

```
$ service firewalld stop
```

Also please use one of the options:

> If you want to connect from external computers to Redis you may adopt one of the following solutions: 1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET protected-mode no' from the loopback interface by connecting to Redis from the same host the server is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE to make this change permanent. 2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode option to 'no', and then restarting the server. 3) If you started the server manually just for testing, restart it with the '--protected-mode no' option. 4) Setup a bind address or an authentication password. NOTE: You only need to do one of the above things in order for the server to start accepting connections from the outside.

As failing to do this will result in error when sending command from external host, in this case docker container.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the server.  The ioredis driver cannot connect to redis. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <ip address>:6379

Comment: I updated the answer and test on my machine and it working, please try now.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to connect with external service like redis by service running inside your container. You can also validate this by executing ping command inside tour container

example -
docker exec -it #container-id# sh

ping #redis ip address#